# Cmake custom target command does not work on all inputs

Tags: c, cmake, gcovr

I am building a number of sources and then running *gcovr* with JSON output:

```
foreach(COMPONENT IN LISTS BLAHDIBLAH)
   ...
   add_custom_command(TARGET ${COMPONENT}_coverage
               COMMAND gcovr --exclude-unreachable-branches -k -r ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} --json -o ${COMPONENT}_coverage_lines.json ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/${COMPONENT}_test.dir/${UNIT_PATH_${COMPONENT}}
               COMMAND gcovr --exclude-unreachable-branches -k -r ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} --json -b -o ${COMPONENT}_coverage_branches.json ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/${COMPONENT}_test.dir/${UNIT_PATH_${COMPONENT}}
   )

   list(APPEND COV_DEPS ${COMPONENT}_coverage)
   ...
endforeach()
```

Later on, I add a `coverage` target to combine the *gcovr* output:

```
    add_custom_target(coverage
            COMMAND gcovr --exclude-unreachable-branches -k -r .. --add-tracefile coverage/*.json --html-details coverage/coverage.html
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
            )
```

If I run `make coverage`, only the first source file is picked up by *gcovr*, but if I run the command manually:

```bash
gcovr --exclude-unreachable-branches -k -r .. --add-tracefile coverage/*.json --html-details coverage/coverage.html
```

... then all the sources are picked up.

Why does that command work in the terminal, but not in CMake?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the custom target. The argument to `--add-tracefile` needs to be enclosed in speech-marks, which themselves need to be escaped:

```
COMMAND gcovr --exclude-unreachable-branches -k -r .. --add-tracefile coverage/*.json --html-details coverage/coverage.html
```

```
COMMAND gcovr --exclude-unreachable-branches -k -r .. --add-tracefile \"coverage/*.json\" --html-details coverage/coverage.html
```